# How does asigning of @property works? (Assigning of a getter to another variable.)

Tags: python, logging, properties, variable-assignment, getter

I have code like this:

```
class Debug(object):
  ...

  @property
  def ThreadAwareLogger(self):
    if not self.logger_instance_for_current_thread:
      self.logger_instance_for_current_thread=self.cloneMainLogger()
    return self.logger_instance_for_current_thread

  def cloneMainLogger(self):
    return logger_instance_for_current_thread

class SomeOtherClass(object):

  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.logger=debug.ThreadAwareLogger

  def otherMethod(self):
    ...
    self.logger.info("Message")
```

The problematic thing is the assignment `self.logger=debug.ThreadAwareLogger`. I'm not sure what is gonna be content of `self.logger`. I want it to be the whole getter and I want to have the getter executed everytime when I use `self.logger` in `SomeOtherClass`. But I'm affraid that in `self.logger` will be stored just the result of the getter `logger_instance_for_current_thread`. That means logger of the thread which was active at the time of assignment. This logger doesn't have to be the right one when I call `self.logger.info("Message")`.

How to get the getter `ThreadAwareLogger` executed everytime when I call `self.logger.info("Message")`?

Sidenote:
Why I actually need the shortcut `self.logger`?
When I decide to replace ThreadAwareLogger with AdvancedThreadAwareLogger I will change just one assignment instead of thousand calls of `self.logger.info("Message")`. Also is None of the business of the `otherMethod` to care about which logger will be used.

**Edit:**

The assignment of getter works as described in the answer by @unutbu. But assigning of the getter causes an issue I didn't think before.

From the `ThreadAwareLogger` I actually call method `cloneMainLogger`. Now the call of someOtherClass.logger ends with exception: AttributeError: 'SomeOtherClass' object has no attribute 'cloneMainLogger'.

So far I bypassed the issue with a small hack. The `SomeOtherClass` actually has a `Debug` instance. So I call `debug.cloneMainLogger()` instead  of `self.cloneMainLogger()` inside of `ThreadAwareLogger`. The program now works, but I consider it really dirty.

**Edit 2:**

If I add line `self.comptreeLogger=Debug.ThreaAwareLogger` inside of a method; e.g. `cloneMainLogger` I'm getting AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'debug'.
Conclusion: I still don't understand the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import logging
import random

class Debug(object):
    @property
    def ThreadAwareLogger(self):
        loggers = [logging.getLogger('abc'),logging.getLogger('def')]
        return self.anotherDebugMethod(loggers)
    def anotherDebugMethod(self,loggers):
        return random.choice(loggers)
class SomeOtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug=Debug()
    @property
    def logger(self):
        return self.debug.ThreadAwareLogger
    def otherMethod(self):
        self.logger.info('Message')

if __name__=='__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)    
    x=SomeOtherClass()
    for i in range(5):
        x.otherMethod()
```

yields output like:

```
INFO:def:Message
INFO:abc:Message
INFO:def:Message
INFO:def:Message
INFO:abc:Message
```

Notice the changes in `abc` and `def` show that the `Debug.ThreadAwareLogger` function is getting called each time.

Comment: Well, there's a little problem with this solution: 

`someOtherClass=SomeOtherClass()`

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'logger'

Comment: I also tried `self.logger=Debug.ThreadAwareLogger`, but with `self.logger` I'm getting only: <property object at 0x7f598e103368>. Dunno how to execute its getter.

Comment: Cool! Now it works! But I ran into another problem. If I call `self.anotherDebugMethod()` from `ThreadAwareLogger`, `someOtherClass.logger` tries to find the `anotherDebugMethod` in self :-(

Comment: @sumid: In that case, I think Owen gave the right answer. I fleshed it out with an example, above.

Comment: I like this solution bit more. I just don't fully understand how it works. (I gonna try Owen's as well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the whole property would be to just make another property:

```
class SomeOtherClass:

    @property
    def logger(self):
        return self.debug.ThreadAwareLogger
```

There might be other ways, too.

Answer (score 1):

`self.logger` will refer to what is returned by the property `ThreadAwareLogger`, not to the property itself.